# Concave functions generating convex set

Tags: convex-analysis

If $g_i$ are concave functions where $i = 1,2,\ldots,m$ and $b_i$ are constants where $i = 1,2,\ldots,m$. Why is the set :

$$ S = {x : g_i(x) \ge b_i i = 1,2,...,m} $$ a convex set?

I know by definition if $f$ is a concave function then
$$ f( tx_1 + (1-t)x_2) \ge tf( x_1) +  (1-t)f(x_2)$$

and $-f(x)$ is a convex function.

Comment: Typo? It should be $ f( tx_1 + (1-t)x_2) \ge tf( tx_1) +  (1-t)f(x_2)$

Comment: First show that the set $S_i = \{ x \mid g_i(x) \ge b_i \}$ is convex for each $i$. Then show that the intersection of convex sets is again convex.

Comment: @MartinR I got stuck showing $$Si={x∣gi(x)≥bi}$$ I think it is related to epigraph or hypograph properties. But could not figure out how.

Comment: You have to show that if $g_i(x_1) \ge b_i$ and $g_i(x_2) \ge b_i$ then also $g_i(tx_1 + (1-t)x_2) \ge b_i$ for $0 < t < 1$, and that follows immediately form the concavity formula.